# How can we loop through all text files in a folder, copy the first N rows from each one, and append the file name of each?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to loop through a bunch of text files, copy the first N-rows from each, and append the file name of each. This is the code that I am testing.

```
# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
import glob
  
  
# use glob to get all the txt files 
# in the folder
path = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\all_files\\'

txt_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))


df_headers = pd.DataFrame()

# loop over the list of files
for f in txt_files:
    with open(f) as myfile:
        print(f)
        firstNlines=myfile.readlines()[0:5]
        df = pd.DataFrame(firstNlines)
        fname = pd.DataFrame({f})
        df_headers = pd.concat([df, fname], axis=1)


df_headers.to_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\out.csv')
```

When I run the code, I get this.

[image]

So, the problem is as follows.

1. I only get one file, which presumably is the last file
2. The data is all tab-delimited, but everything is compressed into one single cell, not split out
3. I'm not sure how to copy the file name down N-rows

What I'd like to end up with is something like this, but with all the files read, not just the last file.

[image]

Comment: Your question has been answered below. Let me also suggest another improvement to your code: `from pathlib import Path; path = Path('C:', 'Users', 'ryans', 'Desktop', 'all_files'); txt_files = path.glob('*.txt')`  (instead of semicolons use new lines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there:

```
# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
import glob
  
# use glob to get all the txt files 
# in the folder
path = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\all_files\\'

txt_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))

df_headers = pd.DataFrame()

# loop over the list of files
num_lines = 5
for f in txt_files:
    with open(f) as myfile:
        first_n_lines = myfile.readlines()[0:num_lines]
        df = pd.DataFrame(first_n_lines)
        df['fname'] = f
        df_headers = pd.concat([df_headers, df], axis=0)
print (df_headers)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get just one file's headers and I'm not getting the file name.

Comment: See the updated code above. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: I just changed 'axis=0' and it does exactly what I want. Thanks so much!!!